# Change related list in page layout

Tags: visualforce, lightning, related-list

We need to know if is possible the following.

We want to replace a related list to a `Visualforce Page` that we create. We want to change it in the page layout. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can add a `Visualforce Page` to your `Page Layout` as long as you set the `StandardController` to the object in question. However, pages included as such will be in a different section of the page, so you don't have quite as much control in that regard. The lowest you can place them is directly above the rest of your standard `Related Lists`.

Here is a basic example of what the page would look like. The key here is the `standardController` attribute, which enables you to add the page to your layout or use it in button overrides, custom button implementations, etc.

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
    <apex:relatedList list="Children__c" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes, I do that. But it becomes to have a strange behavior because when I add a visualforce page to the page layout, it creates a link to see the  complete visualforce. You know how to solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to the link included by default as part of the `relatedList` component? You can build it out using `pageBlockTable` instead. There are *many* examples online if you look around a bit.

Comment: No. The problem is that the visualforce that I included, lightning include it like a link. In the page layout you add the visualforce page and when you visualize it with lightning, it appear a link in the table (but doesn't appear complete) and when you click in it, you can visualize all the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer a sample implementation in this link:
[Customize Related Lists using VisualForce and Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003207)